# When does the need of random data become an assumption?

Tags: provable-security, hardness-assumptions

Suppose an encrypion scheme uses a random string to encrypt and decrypt, which is publicly available, such as an IV or nonce.  In all the cases I am aware of, the existence of say an IV is not "assumed": it is taken as fact that generating a 128 bit IV for example is easy and the existence of such a random IV is not the same as an unproven assumption.

But now suppose an encryption scheme operates with large amounts of publicly accessable random data, say on the order of $2^{256}$ bits.  Then would a proof of security for this cipher have to "assume" the existence of such a database?  In other words, if the security proof of a cipher relied on the existence of a public database storing $2^{256}$ bits, would this be deemed an "assumption", and treated similarly as an "unproven assumption" (like the difficulty of the discrete log problem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In all the cases I am aware of, the existence of say an IV is not "assumed": it is taken as fact that generating a 128 bit IV for example is easy and the existence of such a random IV is not the same as an unproven assumption.

Generally, if (pseudo-)randomness is required, then it is assumed for the block cipher mode (such as CBC) that it actually **is** randomized of course. That's a **pre-condition** which should be indicated in the definition.

> But now suppose an encryption scheme operates with large amounts of publicly accessable random data, say on the order of $2^{256}$ bits.

That's generally not how it works. Even though the IV can be made public *after* encryption, modes such as CBC mode assume that the IV is unpredictable to an adversary *before* such encryption happens.

> Then would a proof of security for this cipher have to "assume" the existence of such a database?

Not for the cipher *algorithm*. Ciphers are not related to databases. A the *protocol* or application specific scheme should definitely take this into account for the system to be secure.

> In other words, if the security proof of a cipher relied on the existence of a public database storing $2^{256}$ bits, would this be deemed an "assumption", and treated similarly as an "unproven assumption" (like the difficulty of the discrete log problem)?

**No, not even that.**

First of all, such a database is known as a **table** in cryptography, even if it is very large.

In the case a cipher uses such a table then it should prove or show the equivalence of the algorithmic use of the table to a known hardness assumption. You cannot just assume that any problem is hard, after all.

What you can assume / make it a precondition that the database consist of random bits. We can certainly create (pseudo-)random bits after all. If that would be useful or not strongly depends.

Of course, storing $2^{256}$ bits in a table is nonsense anyway (that's $1.447 \cdot 10^{49}$ hellabytes!).

---

Note that many modes **do not require a randomized IV**. Many - such as CTR, GCM and ChaCha20 simply require a nonce. For those you just need to keep a synchronized (message) counter. If you want to pluck an IV out of a shared table then you'd need to synchronize offsets anyway.

For CBC mode you can similarly encrypt a counter to create an unpredictable IV, preferably using a separate key.

So you can probably do without the table in the first place.

Comment: Can you expand on "In the case a cipher uses such a table then it should prove or show the equivalence of the use of the table to a known hardness assumption", and in particular what showing equivalence of use of the table to a known hardness assumption would look like?

Comment: I cannot because I don't know how the table would be used. Just specifying a table is not the same as specifying an algorithm after all. And really, that's up to the designer of the algorithm, you cannot start with a table as a solution without a problem.